# Bootstrap Table Export Data issue

Tags: javascript, python, html, twitter-bootstrap, jinja2

I have a Web App written in Python Flask using a Jinja2 template. I am trying to add a Bootstrap table to export data from a table.  So I downloaded and copied the CSS and Javascript files in their proper folders and reference them as below.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/bootstrap.min.css') }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/bootstrap-table.min.css') }}">
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/bootstrap-table.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/bootstrap-table-export.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/tableexport.js') }}"></script>
<script>$("div.navbar-fixed-top").autoHidingNavbar();</script>
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/justified-nav/justified-nav.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.9.2.min.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.bokeh**strong text**.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.9.2.min.js"></script>
```

To create the table, I have this portion of the code:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="pageTables" data-toggle="table" data-show-columns="true" data-search="true" data-show-refresh="true" data-show-toggle="true" data-show-export="true" data-pagination="true" data-click-to-select="true" data-toolbar="#toolbar">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field="E">E</th>
            <th data-field="bthrs">Base </th>
            <th data-field="mag">Mag</th>
            <th data-field="ht">Ho (secs)</th>
            <th data-field="dt">De(secs)</th>
        </tr>
    </thead> 
....

<script>
var $table = $('#table');
$(function () {
    $('#toolbar').find('select').change(function () {
        $table.bootstrapTable('refreshOptions', {
            exportDataType: $(this).val()
        });
    });
})
```

It creates my table, but the Export Data does not work.  Could you please help me on that?

Answer (score 1):

This probably means  that is something wrong with the location of you `bootstrap.table.min.css`.
If you have only this error, please check that the folder where you have 'bootstrap.min.css' also has 'bootstrap.table.min.css'.
If it doesn't exist, try downloading it from:       http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.9.1/bootstrap-table.min.css
P.S: in your code, you seem to have 
`bootstrap.table.min.css`, not 
`bootstrap-table.min.css`. (there is a dot instead of a '-')

Comment: The Error is gone since I fixed the typo. However, the Export data button does not work.

Comment: hmm, i can see that you have  a table there but with the id "pageTables". I cannot run your code, but maybe there is something wrong with the selectors, maybe $table = $('#pageTables') ?

Comment: I used this link to create it. and the <script> is copied from there: https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table-examples/blob/master/extensions/export.html